# Symfony2 OneToOne null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

One user may have just 1 item or none. (1-1..0 relationship)

I'm trying to accomplish that in symfony2 with doctrine.

I've accomplished an 1 to 1 relationship, it's fairly simple. But how can I specify to doctrine that when I want to create an user, the item can be null? (and not to insert a new row and just leave id_item null)

This is what I have:

user.orm.yml file

```
oneToOne:
  userItem:
    targetEntity: SOA\AXBundle\Entity\Items
    cascade: ["remove", "persist"]
    joinColumn:
      name: id_item        
      referencedColumnName: id 
      nullable: true
```

And of course, I created ItemsTypeForm class, and added the type in my userstypeform class:

```
// UsersTypeForm Class
->add('userItem', new \SOA\AXBundle\Form\ItemsTypeForm())
```

When I add a new user, everything goes fine. The user is inserted as well as the item. But when I try to add an user where it has no item (user item fields are blank), I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

It is trying to insert the item, with null values.

While I can live with an 1 to 1 relationship, I would like to learn how to make an 1 to 1..0 relationship.

Comment: I think cascade "persist" creates userItem relation.

Comment: The error talks about a column named 'name', so it does not seem to be related to this relationship. Where is name defined? In the user entity? In the Item entity?

Comment: If "persist" adds an empty userItem (user item fields are blank), then it's the userItem.name that triggers the error.

Comment: protected $userItem = null; ?